# Issues in scroll view

Tags: ios

Actually There are four buttons and there is sub buttons for each button.once I click first button the second button have to move down by giving space for sub buttons but its not working even after setting scroll view.

```
        bgsroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
        bgsroll.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame));
        bgsroll.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        bgsroll.scrollEnabled=YES;
        // bgsroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
        bgsroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
        bgsroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(200, 2000);
        [self.view addSubview:bgsroll];




            happyBtn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
            happyBtn.frame=CGRectMake(MainView.frame.size.width*0.12, MainView.frame.size.height*0.1, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/1.5, 40);
            [happyBtn setTitle:@"Happiness" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [happyBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
            [happyBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapHappy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bgsroll addSubview:happyBtn];

            happyView=[[UIView alloc]init];
            happyView.frame=CGRectMake(MainView.frame.size.width*0.26,CGRectGetHeight(happyBtn.frame)*2.2, CGRectGetWidth(MainView.frame)/1.6, CGRectGetHeight(MainView.frame)/3);
            happyView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
            happyView.layer.borderWidth=0.5;
            happyView.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
            [bgsroll addSubview:happyView];


            LettingGo=[[UIButton alloc]init];
            LettingGo.frame=CGRectMake(happyView.frame.size.width*0.01,happyView.frame.size.height*0.1, CGRectGetWidth(happyView.frame)/1.05, 50);
            [LettingGo setTitle:@"Letting go of negativity" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            LettingGo.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;
            LettingGo.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
            [LettingGo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
            [happyView addSubview:LettingGo];


            LivingPresent=[[UIButton alloc]init];
            LivingPresent.frame=CGRectMake(happyView.frame.size.width*0.01,LettingGo.frame.size.height*1.4, CGRectGetWidth(happyView.frame)/1.05, 40);
            [LivingPresent setTitle:@"Living in the present" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            LivingPresent.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
            [LivingPresent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
            [happyView addSubview:LivingPresent];
            happyView.hidden=YES;


            CreateBtn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
            CreateBtn.frame=CGRectMake(MainView.frame.size.width*0.12, MainView.frame.size.height*0.5, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/1.5, 40);
            [CreateBtn setTitle:@"Happiness" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [CreateBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.400f green:0.737f blue:0.761f alpha:1.00f]];
            [CreateBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapHappy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bgsroll addSubview:CreateBtn];


    -(void)tapHappy:(id)selector{

          happyView.hidden=!happyView.hidden;

     }
```

Comment: Could you share us how you "move" your buttons and i could't see scrollview in here ?

Comment: Could you also share the tapHappy: button action code ?

Comment: You are saying you've tried to "move down" but there is no actually moving the frames of button down in your code. Do you mean hide by moving down ?

Comment: I dont know how to implement that thats why i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

By not working you mean it is not scrolling when the buttons are pushed? I find it easier to scroll elements creating a method that changes the coordinates of elements in subviews through animations. Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      expandButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [expandButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(expandButtonPressed:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)expandButtonPressed:(id)sender{
      if (expanded == NO) {
         expanded = YES;

         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];            
         image1.frame = CGRectMake(image1.frame.origin.x, image1.frame.origin.y+200.0f, image1.frame.size.width, image1.frame.size.height);
         image.frame2 = CGRectMake(image2.frame.origin.x, image2.frame.origin.y+200.0f, image2.frame.size.width, image2.frame.size.height);
         expandButton2.frame = CGRectMake(expandButton2.frame.origin.x, expandButton2.frame.origin.y+200.0f, expandButton2.frame.size.width, expandButton2.frame.size.height);
          expandButton3.frame = CGRectMake(expandButton3.frame.origin.x, expandButton3.frame.origin.y+200.0f, expandButton3.frame.size.width, expandButton3.frame.size.height);

      }completion:nil];
}
```